# How to add button style to each JQuery array elements

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

There is an array of strings in jquery as bellow:

```
$("#preview_tags").val(array.join(', '));
```

with the following results(which in some part of code get changed, when user adds/remove value):

```
A, B, C, ...
```

I need to add the following bootstrap style to each element when new elements get added, but does not work:

```
<button class="btn btn-xs btn-rounded-circle btn-primary">
  <i class="fe fe-check"></i>
</button>
```

What I have tried:

```
$("#preview_tags").val(array.join(`<button class="btn btn-xs btn-rounded-circle btn-primary"><i class="fe fe-check"></i></button>` + ', '));
```

This is the input where tags go in:

```
<small class="text-muted"><textarea disabled="yes" id="preview_tags" name="category-skills></textarea></small>
```

Comment: inputs do not have html elements as children.

Comment: Thanks, but is there any solution for it?

Comment: Yes, you do not use an input for the output. You want something like https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/

Answer (score 0):

To mutate the array to include the HTML between the original values you can use the `map()` method.

Also note that to append HTML to an element you need to use the `html()` method, not `val()`.

```js
let array = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
let html = array.map(l => `${l}<button class="btn btn-xs btn-rounded-circle btn-primary"><i class="fe fe-check"></i></button>`);

$("#preview_tags").val(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="preview_tags"></textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks but it does not work, `preview_tags ` is `textarea` don't no if knowing this matters

Comment: Ah, in that case you need to use `val()`, I've updated the answer to give you the working example. However be aware you cannot display HTML within that element if that is your expectation. It will be shown as text. If you want to show actual HTML then you will need to write you own custom control using HTML, or use an existing third party tag library